# During install locomotive CMS bundle - Permission denied - ruby gems rmagick-2.12.2 install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rmagick, permission-denied

I was installing locamotive's CMS, and this problem happens..

Let me know how can I solve it.

```
Minis-MacBook-Air:~ daraotsu$ cd myapp

Minis-MacBook-Air:myapp daraotsu$ bundle install

Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........

Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..

Resolving dependencies...

Installing rmagick (2.12.2) 

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/daraotsu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rmagick-
2.12.2/README.html

An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.12.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.

Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.12.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: ^probably caused the issue to begin with

Comment: with rvm you should never need sudo since all your gemsets should be owned by the current user.

Answer (score 1):

i would try `sudo gem uninstall rmagick -v '2.12.2'` then try running your bundle again... if that fails remove `/Users/daraotsu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rmagick-
2.12.2` and try to bundle again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try fixing ownership on the `.rvm` directory with `chown -R daraotsu /Users/daraotsu/.rvm`, but I'm thinking your best bet is to uninstall and then reinstall RVM and try again. Somehow you managed to install RVM into your home directory without taking ownership of the files.

Comment: i think reinstalling rvm is using a sledge hammer to fix a trim nail